# Portlets not in columns anymore?

Tags: plone

I'm making a site with plone, and when I first started working with portlets, they suddenly were at the bottom of the page. In the picture, "Noticias" is a right column portlet.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23574503/portlet.jpg

I wanted to have the left and right collumn portlet layout back. I don't really know how have I done this, the only code I changed was the current theme css and this behaviour is not related to the theme, as it also happens with the default one.

Anyone has suggestions?

Thank you for the help.

edit: If I change the theme on @@theme-controlpanel from sunburst to plone classic, the columns work.

Comment: Ok, this may not be the most correct way to do it, but found an awnser. 

Don't really know why, but the columns.css of the sunburst theme was empty. So I went here:

https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.sunburst/blob/master/plonetheme/sunburst/skins/sunburst_styles/columns.css

And added this code to the current theme.

Answer (score 1):

according to your screenshot you've installed a special theme
("theme by css templates plone integration by nekorin")

most probably the columns are re-arranged by this theme. if you deactivate this theme you'll get the default behaviour (left and right) back.

Comment: No, as I said on the question, this started happening independently of the theme. With this same theme, I had the columns before.

Comment: either mobile.css moved them there (try to deactivate this one in css_registry) or your theme. plain plone with sunburst theme will show columns left and right.